# Как в .htaccess разрешить доступ к css, расположенным в папке модуля Yii 2 (basic)

Tags: .htaccess, yii2

Добрый день. Разрабатываю небольшое приложение на Yii 2 (использую шаблон basic). Столкнулся с тем, что css-файл, который я хочу использовать для оформления модуля и который расположен в структуре модуля, не подключается. Вот порядок моих действий:

1. Создал файл шаблона для модуля */modules/admin/views/layouts/main.php*
2. В файле */modules/admin/Module.php* в методе ***init()*** указал, что буду использовать этот шаблон для модуля.
3. В папке модуля создал папку *css* и в ней - файл */modules/admin/css/admin_style.css*
4. В папке модуля создал папку *assets* и в ней файл */modules/admin/assets/AdminAsset.php*, в котором указал, что хочу подключить */modules/admin/css/admin_style.css*
5. В файле шаблона указал, что буду использовать AdminAsset:

   use app\modules\admin\assets\AdminAsset;

   AdminAsset::register($this);
6. В панели разработчика вижу, что мой css-файл зарегистрирован, но не может подключиться (статус 404):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подозреваю, что причина в том, что папка с css-файлами не является публичной и нужно разрешить к ней доступ *.htaccess*. В своём приложении я использую 2 файла *.htaccess*: в папке */web* и в корне. В папке */web* такой:

```
RewriteEngine On RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php
```

А в корне - вот такой:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(web)
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ /web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ web/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ web/images/$1 [L]
RewriteRule (.*) /web/$1
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /web/index.php
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, а то я в директивах .htaccess не силён.

P.S. Ещё есть желание для загрузки файлов использовать папку */uploads*, а не */web/uploads*, но это, по-моему, вопрос из той же плоскости

Comment: а `admin_style.css` по какому адресу пытается загрузиться? из _site.com/assets/xxxx/admin_style.css_?

Comment: http://site.com/modules/admin/css/admin_style.css

Comment: выложи пожалуйста код `AdminAsset.php`, там ошибочка думаю

Comment: Спасибо, ты натолкнул меня на решение. Действительно, проблема была в путях в AdminAsset.php. Написал так - и всё заработало:
    `public $sourcePath = '@app/modules/admin';`

    `public $css = [`
        `'css/module_admin.css',`
        `'css/new.css',`
    `];`

Но пришлось вручную удалить кэш из web/assets/. Как сделать так, чтобы он там не создавался в режиме DEV?

Comment: Наверное тут найдёшь решение - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24819220/yii2-assets-clear-cache